# sudo yum install apache2 on amazon linux fails

Tags: linux, ubuntu, yum, apt, apache2

I've tried running the command:`sudo yum install apache2` and got the following error:

```
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
amzn-main/latest                     | 2.1 kB     00:00     
amzn-updates/latest                  | 2.3 kB     00:00     
No package apache2 available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

I'm a linux newbie on Ubuntu (newbie there too) `sudo apt-get install apache2` works why?

Answer (score 6):

The default package manager for installing packages in Ubuntu is `apt-get` not `yum`. So it is the best to use `apt-get` for installing packages and not `yum`.

To install apache with `yum` you can execute:

```
sudo yum install httpd
```

Comment: The core of this answer is the following: The name of the package on your system, which appears to be Amazon Linux, is `httpd` and not `apache2` like on Ubuntu.